# How do I make my code concise and short using Regex Expressions

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm trying to make the code a lot cleaner and concise. The main goal I want to do is to change the string to my requirements .

Requirements

- I want to remove any empty lines (like the one in the middle of the two sentences down below)
- I want to remove the * in front of each sentence, if there is.
- I want to make the first letter of each word capital and the rest lowercase (except words that have $ in front of it)

This is what I've done so far:

```js
const string =
  `*SQUARE HAS ‘NO PLANS’ TO BUY MORE BITCOIN: FINANCIAL NEWS
$SQ

*$SQ UPGRADED TO OUTPERFORM FROM PERFORM AT OPPENHEIMER, PT $185`

const nostar = string.replace(/\*/g, ''); // gets rid of the * of each line
const noemptylines = nostar.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm, ''); //gets rid of empty blank lines
const lowercasestring = noemptylines.toLowerCase(); //turns it to lower case
const tweets = lowercasestring.replace(/(^\w{1})|(\s{1}\w{1})/g, match => match.toUpperCase()); //makes first letter of each word capital
console.log(tweets)
```

I've done most of the code, however, I want to keep words that have $ in front of it, capital, which I don't know how to do.
Furthermore, I was wondering if its possible to combine regex expression, so its even shorter and concise.

Comment: As the old saying goes, "If you look at a problem and think, I'll solve this using regular expression, you now have two problems" :)

Comment: Conciseness isn't a goal you should be aiming for. [*"Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand."*](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Martin_Fowler)

Comment: Totally agree with you. It is bad habit I'm working on to get rid of. Appreciate the advice, I'll remember that quote next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of capture groups and the callback function of [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

```
^(\*|[\r\n]+)|\$\S*|(\S+)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(\*|[\r\n]*$)` Capture **group 1**, match either `*` or 1 or more newlines
- `|` Or
- `\$\S*` Match `$` followed by optional non whitespace chars (which will be returned unmodified in the code)
- `|` Or
- `(\S+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ non whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iUaVaS/1)

```js
const regex = /^(\*|[\r\n]+)|\$\S*|(\S+)/gm;
const string =
  `*SQUARE HAS ‘NO PLANS’ TO BUY MORE BITCOIN: FINANCIAL NEWS
$SQ

*$SQ UPGRADED TO OUTPERFORM FROM PERFORM AT OPPENHEIMER, PT $185`;

const res = string.replace(regex, (m, g1, g2) => {
  if (g1) return ""
  if (g2) {
    g2 = g2.toLowerCase();
    return g2.toLowerCase().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + g2.slice(1);
  }
  return m;
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Appreciate you explaining and simplifying this for my understanding. I will look into capture groups and the call back function in depth :)

Answer (score 2):

Making it readable is more important than making it short.

```
const tweets = string
  .replace(/\*/g, '') // gets rid of the * of each line
  .replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm, '') //gets rid of empty blank lines
  .toLowerCase() //turns it to lower case
  .replace(/(^\w{1})|(\s{1}\w{1})/g, match => match.toUpperCase()) //makes first letter of each word capital
  .replace(/\B\$(\w+)\b/g, match => match.toUpperCase()); //keep words that have $ in front of it, capital
```